# Access NSWindow's Element via Child NSView/ViewController

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, nsview, nswindow

Is it possible to access a NSWindowController's element from a child NSViewController?

Essentially I have a NSProgressIndicator that spins on the bottom corner of the NSWindow. This works because my WebView is in my NSWindowController instead of my NSViewController.

I want to break the logic apart now but I'm having trouble understanding how I'd access these elements from my View Controller.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing. What do you mean by an "element" of an `NSWindowController`? A `WebView` isn't "in" an `NSWindowController` or an `NSViewController`. Do you mean in a NIB which is owned and loaded by one of those controllers? You say "This works because ...". What does "this" refer to? What does "works" mean here?

Comment: I'd like to be able to hook up something (in this case a NSProgressIndicator) in my window's xib to an IBOutlet coming from my ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect an outlet from one NIB to an object in another and the desire to do so indicates a problem with your design.  If the view is so intimately connected to other things in the window, maybe it shouldn't be separated out into a different NIB.

A view should only go into a separate NIB when it makes sense as a self-contained unit.  It should represent and manipulate its controller's `representedObject` and not much more. The controller might have a delegate that it informs about what's being done and asks to make customizing decisions.

Maybe you can continue to use a separate NIB if you adopt that sort of design.  Perhaps the window will have a reference to some model object.  It would configure the view controller to use that model object as its represented object. And perhaps the progress indicator would be bound to that same model object. Then, as the view manipulates its represented object, it would *indirectly* also affect the progress indicator.

Another option would be for the window controller to set itself as the delegate for the view controller and your view controller could invoke it at appropriate points to inform it of things going on in the view. Then the window controller could do whatever was appropriate to the progress indicator or other stuff in the window outside of the view. This hypothetical delegate is something you would have to add to the view controller class and you'd design its protocol.